# Error 'undefined columns selected' - Chord diagram (circlize package) in R

Tags: r, chord, circlize

I need some help with an error message returning when using the `chordDiagram()` function from the `circlize` package.

I am working with fisheries landings. Fishing vessels start their trip in one port (homeport `PORT_DE`), and land their catch (scallops in this case) in another port (landing port `PORT_LA` ). I am trying to draw a chord diagram using `circlize` package to visualise the flow of landings between ports. I have 161 unique ports and the port names are stored as `character` strings.

Before calling the `chordDiagram()` function to draw the chord diagram, I store the relevant columns in a dummy object (`m`).

```
# Store relevant column
m <- data.frame(PORT_DE = VMS_by_trips$PORT_DE_Label, 
            PORT_LA = VMS_by_trips$PORT_LA_Label, 
            SCALLOP_W = VMS_by_trips$Trip_SCALLOP_W)

head(m)
# PORT_DE  PORT_LA SCALLOP_W
# 1  Arbroath Arbroath  2.147143
# 2  Eyemouth Aberdeen  8.791970
# 3    Buckie Aberdeen  2.025833
# 4  Montrose Aberdeen  8.268540
# 5  Aberdeen Aberdeen  1.358286
# 6 Peterhead Aberdeen  0.797500
```

I then create an adjacency matrix using `dcast()` and rename rows.

```
require(reshape2)
m <- as.matrix(dcast(m, PORT_DE ~ PORT_LA, value.var = "SCALLOP_W", fun.aggregate = sum))
dim(m) #adjecency matrix represents port pairs
#[1] 153 138

row.names(m) <- m[,1]
m <- m[,2:dim(m)[2]]
class(m) <- "numeric"
```

Finally, I call the plot function `chordDiagram()` .

```
library(circlize) 
chordDiagram(m)
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error message.

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, c(1, 2, 5)) : undefined columns selected
```

If I replace the row and column names with numbers, the function runs, and the correct plot is returned.

```
row.names(m) <- 1:153
colnames(m) <- 1:137
```

Any ideas how to run the function with the actual port names?

I have already tried to remove special characters, replace `" "` spaces with `"_"` underscores, keep a smaller number of characters, keep only a few port pairs. Unfortunately the same error keeps appearing. Any help appreciated.

> Please note that since posting this question, I have managed to create the
>   visualisation needed. Here is a link to another related question,
>   which also includes the code to adjust various settings of a chord
>   diagram.
>
> [Adjust highlight.sector() width and placement - Chord diagram (circlize package) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723254/adjust-highlight-sector-width-and-placement-chord-diagram-circlize-package)

Comment: `chordDiagram` will work on a data frame as well as a matrix.. see `?chordDiagramFromDataFrame`

Comment: @gjabel Thank you for prompt response. I will have a look and respond here if I manage to resolve myself.

Comment: I tried your six-line data (by `head(m)`) with the code you attached, there is no error occurs. Can you attach the full dataset? On the other hand, `chordDiagram()` can be applied directly to the data frame and you don't need to convert it to a matrix.

Comment: @ZuguangGu Thank you for responding to my questions via email. I have now posted the answer to my question below for the benefit of the stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @ZuguangGu, the reason for the error message was the `NAs` in my column names. If you remove them first, then the chord diagram plots just fine. Following the same notation, please see below.

```
#create adjacency matrix
m <- data.frame(PORT_DE = VMS_by_trips$PORT_DE_Label, 
                PORT_LA = VMS_by_trips$PORT_LA_Label, 
                SCALLOP_W = VMS_by_trips$Trip_SCALLOP_W)


#Check for NA values in your dataset
which(is.na(m[, 1]))
which(is.na(m[, 2]))

#Remove the rows which have NA values, there will not be errors any more.
df = m
df = df[!(is.na(df[[1]]) | is.na(df[[2]])), ]

require(reshape2)
m <- dcast(df, PORT_DE ~ PORT_LA, value.var = "SCALLOP_W", fun.aggregate = sum)
row.names(m) <- m[,1]
m <- as.matrix(m[, -1])

# remove self-links
m2 = m
cn = intersect(rownames(m2), colnames(m2)) 
for(i in seq_along(cn)) {
  m2[cn[i], cn[i]] = 0
}

# Export 3 versions of the chord diagram in a PDF

library(circlize) 

pdf("test.pdf")

# Use all data
chordDiagram(m)
title("using all data")

#remove self-links
chordDiagram(m2)
title("remove self-links")

#here reduce = 0.01 means to remove ports which have capacity less than 0.01 of capacity of all ports.
chordDiagram(m2, reduce = 0.01)
title("remove self-links and small sectors")

dev.off()
```