# Adjust highlight.sector() width and placement - Chord diagram (circlize package) in R

Tags: r, plot, chord-diagram, circos

I need some help with adjusting highlighted sectors of a `chordDiagram()` from the circlize package.

I am working with fisheries landings data. Fishing vessels start their trip in one port (homeport `PORT_DE`), and land their catch in another port (landing port `PORT_LA`). I am working with scallops live weight in tonnes (landings `SCALLOP_W`). Here is a simple example of the dataframe:

```
        PORT_DE  PORT_LA SCALLOP_W
1      Aberdeen Aberdeen       116
2        Barrow   Barrow        98
3       Douglas   Barrow       127
4 Kirkcudbright   Barrow       113
5       Brixham  Brixham        69
6        Buckie   Buckie       180
```

Each port (`Name_short`) is labeled by region (`Region_lb`), and by country (`Country_lb`). Example below.

```
   Name_short Country_lb      Region_lb
1   Scalloway   Scotland Shetland Isles
2   Scrabster   Scotland    North Coast
3      Buckie   Scotland    Moray Firth
4 Fraserburgh   Scotland    Moray Firth
5    Aberdeen   Scotland     North East
```

Using the `circilze` package, I have generated a customised `chordDiagram` to visualise the flow of landings between ports. I have adjusted most of the settings, including grouping of ports of the same nation, by adjusting the spacing between sectors (see `gap.after` setting). This is the current form of my chord diagram,

[image: Flow diagram (chord) of landings between ports]

I have nearly produced what I want, apart from the final touch of highlighting sectors by country. I am trying to use `highlight.sector()` in order to highlight ports of the same country, but I cannot adjust either the width or the placement of the highlighted sector. Currently, the country sectors overlap with all the other labels. Example below:

[image]

> Please note that there are different colours between the two figures
>   as colours are randomly generated.

Could you please assist me with the final adjustments?

Code for producing the figures shown below:

```
# calculate gaps by country; 
# 1 degree between ports, 10 degree between countries
gaps <- rep(1, nrow(port_coords))
gaps[cumsum(as.numeric(tapply(port_coords$Name_short, port_coords$Country_lb, length)))] <- 10

# edit initialising parameters
circos.par(canvas.ylim=c(-1.5,1.5), # edit  canvas size 
           gap.after = gaps, # adjust gaps between regions
           track.margin = c(0.01, 0)) # adjust bottom and top margin 
                                      # (blank area out of the plotting regio)

# Plot chord diagram
chordDiagram(m,

             # manual order of sectors
             order = port_coords$Name_short,

             # plot only grid (no labels, no axis)
             annotationTrack = "grid", 
             preAllocateTracks = 1, 

             # adjust grid width and spacing
             annotationTrackHeight = c(0.03, 0.01), 

             # add directionality
             directional=1, 
             direction.type = c("diffHeight", "arrows"), 
             link.arr.type = "big.arrow",

             # adjust the starting end of the link
             diffHeight = -uh(1, "mm"),

             # adjust height of all links
             h.ratio = 0.8,

             # add link border
             link.lwd = 1, link.lty = 1, link.border="gray35"

             )

# add labels and axis manually
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")

  # print labels & text size (cex)
  circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + .7, sector.name, 
              facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5), cex=0.6)

  # print axis
  circos.axis(h = "top", labels.cex = 0.5, major.tick.percentage = 0.2, 
              sector.index = sector.name, track.index = 2)
}, bg.border = NA)

# add additional track to enhance the visual effect of different groups
# Scotland
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "Scotland")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "blue",
                 text = "Scotland", cex = 0.8, text.col = "white", niceFacing = TRUE)
# England
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "England")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "red",
                 text = "England", cex = 0.8, text.col = "white", niceFacing = TRUE)
# Wales
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "Wales")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "forestgreen",
                 text = "Wales", cex = 0.8, text.col = "white", niceFacing = TRUE)
# Isle of Man
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "Isle of Man")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "darkred",
                 text = "Isle of Man", cex = 0.8, text.col = "white", niceFacing = TRUE)
# Rep. Ireland
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "Rep. Ireland")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "darkorange2",
                 text = "Ireland", cex = 0.8, text.col = "white", niceFacing = TRUE)
# N.Ireland
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "N.Ireland")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "magenta4",
                 text = "N. Ireland", cex = 0.8, text.col = "white", niceFacing = TRUE)

# re-set circos parameters
circos.clear()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been trying for a while now to find a solution. I have now managed to adjust the placement and the width of the `highlight.sector()` by adjusting the default track margins and default track height.

I have done so by specifying `track.margin` and `track.height` parameters in the initialisation of `circos.par()` step.

The end product looks like below. Code at the end the answer.

[image]

```
# calculate gaps by country; 
# 1 degree between ports, 10 degree between countries
gaps <- rep(1, nrow(port_coords))
gaps[cumsum(as.numeric(tapply(port_coords$Name_short, port_coords$Country_lb, length)))] <- 10

# edit initialising parameters
circos.par(canvas.ylim=c(-1.5,1.5), # edit  canvas size 
           gap.after = gaps, # adjust gaps between regions
           track.margin = c(0.01, 0.05), # adjust bottom and top margin
           # track.margin = c(0.01, 0.1)
           track.height = 0.05)

# Plot chord diagram
chordDiagram(m,

             # manual order of sectors
             order = port_coords$Name_short,

             # plot only grid (no labels, no axis)
             annotationTrack = "grid",
             # annotationTrack = NULL, 
             preAllocateTracks = 1, 

             # adjust grid width and spacing
             annotationTrackHeight = c(0.03, 0.01), 

             # add directionality
             directional=1, 
             direction.type = c("diffHeight", "arrows"), 
             link.arr.type = "big.arrow",

             # adjust the starting end of the link
             diffHeight = -uh(1, "mm"),

             # adjust height of all links
             h.ratio = 0.8,

             # add link border
             link.lwd = 1, link.lty = 1, link.border="gray35"

             # track.margin = c(0.01, 0.1)

             )

# Scotland
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "Scotland")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "blue2",
                 text = "Scotland", cex = 1, text.col = "white", 
                 niceFacing = TRUE, font=2)
# England
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "England")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "red2",
                 text = "England", cex = 1, text.col = "white", 
                 niceFacing = TRUE, font=2)
# Wales
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "Wales")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "springgreen4",
                 text = "Wales", cex = 1, text.col = "white", 
                 niceFacing = TRUE, font=2)
# Isle of Man
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "Isle of Man")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "orangered4",
                 text = "Isle of Man", cex = 1, text.col = "white", 
                 niceFacing = TRUE, font=2)
# Rep. Ireland
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "Rep. Ireland")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "darkorange3",
                 text = "Ireland", cex = 1, text.col = "white", 
                 niceFacing = TRUE, font=2)
# N.Ireland
highlight.sector(port_coords$Name_short[which(port_coords$Country_lb == "N.Ireland")],
                 track.index = 1, col = "magenta4",
                 text = "NI", cex = 1, text.col = "white", 
                 niceFacing = TRUE, font=2)

# add labels and axis manually
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")

  # print labels & text size (cex)
  # circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + .7, sector.name, 
  #             facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5), cex=0.6)

  circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + 2, sector.name, 
              facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5), cex=0.6)

  # print axis
  circos.axis(h = "bottom", labels.cex = 0.5, 
              # major.tick.percentage = 0.05, 
              major.tick.length = 0.6,
              sector.index = sector.name, track.index = 2)
}, bg.border = NA)

# re-set circos parameters
circos.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're a little ocd like myself, you could also add the sector.numeric.index into the sectors and add a legend on the side, so it looks just a tad better like [this](https://github.com/timxymo/Chord-Diagram-Visualization/blob/master/with%20legend.png?raw=true), just my 2 cents!